# fixed Point function bug

Tags: python

My function is almost correct, however there's a bug somewhere.
Can you help me with fixing it?

```
def fixedPoint(f, epsilon):
    """
    f: that's a function which will return a float
    epsilon: it's a float(a small one)

    returns the best guess when that guess is less than epsilon 
    away from f(guess) or after 100 trials, whichever comes first.
    """
    guess = 1.0
    for i in range(100):
        if f(guess) - guess < epsilon:
            return guess
        else:
            guess = f(guess)
    return guess
```

Comment: What does f(guess) do? also, what error are you getting?

Comment: Please add details on the bug that occurrs.

Comment: abs(f(guess)-guess) < epsilon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
if abs(f(guess) - guess) < epsilon:
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks, that's was just what I was looking for.